# Standalone Component is not showed for debugging in webpack:source when using unsupported NOde version

Tags: angular, typescript

I created these two components:

[image]

After using ng serve i can see only one component in source of the chrome browser:

[image]

How can i debug the standalone component? Breakpoints also can not be hitted with vs code with this config:

```
{
  "name": "ng serve",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:4200/"
},
```

**Update: using the supported node version for Angular Cli solves this problem!**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for making this question but the problem was that i used the newest lts version of node (18.x.x). So for some reason it didnt work with angular cli 14. I noticed this when i typed ng version in the console. After downgrading to node 16.10 according to this page: https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3 everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can always debug the good old school way:

`console.log(someVar);`

You can then verify the content of your variables and it will be displayed in your browser console, regardless of what Angular does to your code (transpilation, compilation into a bundle, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, but i dont like to do this. Because in complex situation it is very helpful to have a proper debug tool via browser or in VS Code